# User Controls and Windows in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am making a wpf application. I am very new to WPF.
I have a main layout screen which has a background content and other screens that have the layout plus some more controls exclusive to those screens.

I am doing it as:

The main layout screen is a Window and the other dedicated screens are user controls.

For every specialized screen, I am doing this:

```
Application.Current.MainWindow mw;
mw.Content = nameOfCurrentUserControl;
```

Is this idea fine?

Comment: to counter that question : ask yourself this : does it suit your needs?
the downside of this, is that implicit databinding probably won't work, and explicit databinding will have to be done from C# code, rather than XAML.

Comment: I thought on similar lines but I don't have a clear picture, being new to WPF. Could you please give an example of explicit data binding? or any link that could help.

Comment: Implicit data binding comes from setting the datacontext of an element. The child elements will then be implicitly databound. you can change this by explicitly setting the datacontext. it would look like this : `nameOfCurrentUserControl.DataContext = myDataObject` (you could go much further in depth, but i think that is beyond the scope of the question

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to have a program with different pages. Like a wizard for instalation.

Then what you want to do is to create a Window (as you did) and inside it add a `Frame`.
Then you create `Pages` and in each page you create the layout you want.

Then in your main Window, you create instances of your Pages (mySecondPage = new SecondPage()) and then you `Navigate` from one page to the other loading them into the frame of the main Window using `MyFrame.Navigate(mySecondPage)`

Here you have much more information about navigation : http://paulstovell.com/blog/wpf-navigation

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out. Any advantage of using pages over user controls?

Comment: I agree with you that it would be a good use case for pages. However, `Pages` and the `NavigationContainer` you need to use, limit the application quite heavily.

Comment: @Domysee do pages *have* to be used in conjunction with a `NavigationContainer`?

Comment: @TimothyGroote either `NavigationContainer` or `Frame`. afaik the limitations are the same. You cannot have multiple active views (a collection in a TabControl for example), no animations on view change (e.g. fade in/out) and probably some others I dont recall at the moment.